# AWS S3 Uploader/iOS: The file couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ios9

I am trying to upload an image to amazon s3 using the official pod.

To get the file path I am using the PHImageManager object and then just read the info object.

Here is the code:

```
//Getting the file:
[selectedPhotos enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset *obj, NSUInteger objIdx, BOOL *objEnumerator) {

    [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:obj options:nil
                                     resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {

        NSString *fileName = kFileName;
        NSString *fileUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", kS3Root, kBucket, fileName];
        NSURL *path = [info objectForKey:@"PHImageFileURLKey"];
        if (path) {
            [self uploadToS3:path andUniqueName:fileName];
        }


    }];
}];


// Upload function - example:
- (void) uploadToS3:(NSURL*) filePath andUniqueName:(NSString*) uniqueName {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    AWSS3TransferManager * transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager S3TransferManagerForKey:@"USEast1S3TransferManager"];
    AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];

    uploadRequest.body = filePath;
    uploadRequest.bucket = kBucket;
    uploadRequest.key = uniqueName;
    uploadRequest.contentType = kFileType;

    [[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
        if (task.error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
        }
        if (task.exception) {
            NSLog(@"Exception: %@", task.exception);
        }
        if (task.result) {

        }
        return nil;
    }];
});
```

}

I am always getting the same error:

```
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “IMG_6651.JPG” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/106APPLE/IMG_6651.JPG, NSUnderlyingError=0x13013d620 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, I've made changes and now I have a different issue:

```
// After pick an image
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:obj options:options
                                     resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {

        NSString *fileName = kFileName;
        NSString *fileUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", kS3Root, kBucket, fileName];
        [self uploadToS3:imageData andUniqueName:fileName];

        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        UIImage* resizedImage = [img resizedImageByMagick: @"320x320#"];

        NSData *fileData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImage, 0.8);
        NSString *base64String = [fileData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

        NSDictionary *dict = @{@"timestamp": kFirebaseServerValueTimestamp, @"image": base64String, @"url":fileUrl};
        [[self.firebase childByAutoId] setValue:dict];
    }];

//Upload function
- (void) uploadToS3:(NSData*) data andUniqueName:(NSString*) uniqueName {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSURL *tmp = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp"]];
    [data writeToURL:tmp atomically:YES];

    AWSS3TransferManager * transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager S3TransferManagerForKey:@"USEast1S3TransferManager"];
    AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];

    uploadRequest.body = tmp;
    uploadRequest.bucket = kBucket;
    uploadRequest.key = uniqueName;
    uploadRequest.contentType = kFileType;

    [[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
        if (task.error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
        }
        if (task.exception) {
            NSLog(@"Exception: %@", task.exception);
        }
        if (task.result) {
            NSLog(@"Result: %@", task.result);
        }
        return nil;
    }];
});
}
```

**ERROR:**
    AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSURLSessionManager.m line:260 | -[AWSURLSessionManager URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:] | Session task failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "cannot parse response" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x160150890 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1017 "(null)"

Any help, please?

Comment: You should [turn on verbose logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html) and investigate the log. By the way, you should take a look at `AWSS3TransferUtility` instead of `AWSS3TransferManager`. The transfer manager is not actively maintained anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, Now I am using AWSS3TransferUtility, but it seems the only way to do it for me is using a Cognito identity.

Comment: You can implement your own credentials provider for `AWSS3TransferUtility`. It's exactly the same as `AWSS3TransferManager`.

Comment: Well, Cognito looks more easy to set up. I am trying, thank you!